# Android: Synchronized Game Loops

Tags: android, time, synchronization

I am staring to build my first android game and I'm looking for a little help on how to keeps everything running smooth on all phones. My idea was to call a function after x seconds has elapsed but I'm not sure if thats the best approach

Comment: You should post more detail on what you're trying to *do*, since it's incredibly vague right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the Simple Game Architecture contains Input, Update State and Render. So you have to consider FPS and UPS for your updating state condition. And there will be obviously synchronized block for particular thread. But that would be something vague as you can go through the tutorials in [Obviam](http://obviam.net) or read the Book from Apress for the Beginning Android Games... I can give you some efficient links for Game Development on Android...